# Криптографический алгоритм Serpent

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток!

Интересует реализация криптографического алгоритм Serpent на C#. В Интернете ничего внятного не нашел. Может, у кого-то есть или ссылка, например?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Раз](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/)

> Current feature list:
>
> Symmetric key algorithms: ..., Serpent, ...

[Два](https://github.com/rzymek01/bsk-serpent)

> Simple C# app allows encrypt/decrypt file using Serpent

Answer (score 1):

Есть широко известный в узких кругах API/криптопровайдер [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/)

В нем числе прочих также реализован Serpent.

Поройтесь в документации - там все довольно просто. Естественно надо понимать, что такое паддинг, сцепление блоков, генерация ключей, выбор ГСЧ и проч. криптографические премудрости. Без этого будет сложновато.